# Restart run or debug mode when clicking on the button again

Tags: intellij-idea

When I used to click `Run` or `Debug`in IntelliJ, it used to restart the running process but, now it spins up a new one. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure [Allow parallel run option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYA7o.png) is disabled in the Run/Debug configuration.

Comment: @Crt then please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as [I can't reproduce the described behavior](https://i.imgur.com/4SgHLPd.png).